# How to deduce a template before a varidic template

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I currently have the following problem my function template has to be declared before the variadic template and the compiler is unable to deduce it.

```
template<class F, class... Ts>
void update(F f){
    for(auto t: get_range<Ts...>()){
        apply(std::forward<F>(f), t);
    }
}
..
cg.update<decltype(ftest),int,float>(ftest);
..
```

Is there a good workaround for this problem? I would like to call it like this

```
cg.update<int,float>(ftest);
```

I believe that in C++17 I can write

```
template<class... Ts>
void update(auto f){
    for(auto t: get_range<Ts...>()){
        apply(f, t);
    }
}
```

but clang doesn't seem to support it just yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put the `class F` parameter after the variadic `class... Ts` parameter.

```
template<class... Ts>
void get_range(){ }

auto x = [](auto){};

template<class... Ts, class F>
void update(F f)
{        
    // The following `static_assert` assumes the function is being
    // instantiated with `<int,float>`. It's just here to prove
    // that `F` is not part of `Ts...`.

    // Make sure that `F` is not being caught in `Ts...`:
    static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) == 2, "");

    // Make sure that `F` is actually `decltype(x)`:
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(f), decltype(x)>{}, "");

    // Call your function:
    get_range<Ts...>();
}

int main() 
{       
    update<int,float>(x);
    return 0;
}
```

[ideone example](http://ideone.com/PBKF46)

Comment: Great answer, +1, for some (false) reason I always had the impression that the variadic type has to be the last. But you proved me wrong.

Comment: Thanks that was much simpler than I thought it would be but I think there is a  slight mistake, shouldn't it be 

`static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) == 1, "");`
?

Comment: @vsoftco: That's the case for (unspecialized) class templates, but not function templates. [ideone example](http://ideone.com/E9ahxt)

Comment: @MaikKlein: no - I'm calling `update<int, float>`. `sizeof...(Ts)` returns the number of types in the variadic pack. The first type is `int`, the second type is `float`. Therefore, `sizeof...(Ts)` should be two.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo One more thing I learnt ;) Any reason why it's not allowed for structs, aside from the fact that there is no template type deduction going on?

Comment: @vsoftco: I think that's the issue - there's no way the compiler can figure out if the last type should be part of the pack or not, so it forces variadic packs to be at the end. I'm not sure if there is any other reason for this restriction :)

Comment: @vsoftco: There is [a C++17 proposal for template argument deduction from constructors](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0091r0.html) - not sure if the rules will change then

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Yeah I heard about that, will be great to avoid all those `make_Foo(...)` factory functions.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, It seems the proposal was taken well. The author is working on standard wording for the next meeting, so I think it has a good chance of being in C++17. You can find more information in [this trip report](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2015/11/09/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-kona-october-2015/).